# ERROR [karma-server]: UncaughtException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am having an error when I run `npm test` or `ng test` for my angular project.
I tried installing node_modules again but did not work. please help me understand what is the issue.

```
ERROR [karma-server]: UncaughtException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of undefined
    at new Reporter (/Users/app/node_modules/istanbul-api/lib/reporter.js:24:43)
    at Object.createReporter (/Users/app/node_modules/istanbul-api/index.js:16:16)
    at createReport (/Users/app/node_modules/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter/src/reporter.js:91:31)
    at/Users/app/node_modules/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter/src/reporter.js:217:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at BrowserCollection.forEach (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/browser_collection.js:91:26)
    at CoverageIstanbulReporter.onRunComplete (/Users/app/node_modules/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter/src/reporter.js:216:16)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:40:26)
    at Server.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at emitRunCompleteIfAllBrowsersDone (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:320:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:356:9)
    at Server.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:332:14)
    at Server.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at Browser.onComplete (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:94:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/app/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:216:44)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at /Users/app/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:435:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I have simple test case for should create like following:

```js
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            imports: [
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            providers: []
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Error stack suggests that there is a problem while creating a coverage report using an Istanbul reporter. May you please attach karma and jasmine configs? I guess it could be something there

Comment: you can check my configfile 
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9aau8s?file=src%2Fkarma.conf.js)

Comment: I have found mistake there was typo in my karma.conf.js file Thank you.